# I have coded to import python modules into main.py . But I have problem to import

Tags: python, module, sys

E:\Karya\Python <-- main.py inside here

E:\Karya\packages\extra< -- iota.py inside here

```
import sys
sys.path.append('E:\Karya')
sys.path.append('E:\Karya\Python')
    
from ..packages.extra import iota
    
print(iota.FunI())
```

Question:call function FunI() by import iota.py

ERROR :
$ C:/Users/ready/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/python3.9.exe e:/Karya/Python/main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "e:\Karya\Python\main.py", line 5, in 
from ..packages.extra import iota
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

detail:

[tree directory, main.py inside python folder and iota.py inside extra folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VlCmT.png)

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GJy6S.png)

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fH3mA.png)

Comment: With windows paths, you need an extra ```\``` for every ```\```.  i.e. ```sys.path.append('E:\\Karya')```

Comment: I have tried it but the error still the same

Comment: Please clarify where the files are.  I don't quite follow where main.py and iota.py resides.

Comment: Pls Dont link images. Add details as text in the question

Comment: I have edited it

Comment: If you're appending the required path, I would think that you just do something like ```from packages.extra import iota```

Comment: if I remove the '..' before the package, there will be additional yellow underscores on the words

Comment: Thx Bro its work ,but i want use sys .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add **packages** directory to **sys.path** and import **iota** from **extra**

```py
sys.path.append("E:\\Karya\\packages")
from extra import iota
```

> **Make sure that there is ***init**.py* file in *extra* directory (and I think it is needed in *packages* directory too)**